# Hibernate, dealing with Criteria and left outer join condition

Tags: java, hibernate

I've an existing piece of code like follow:

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(myClass);
crit.createAlias(TAB1, TAB1, JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
crit.createAlias(TAB1 + ".table2", TAB2, JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
crit.add(Restrictions.eq(TAB1 + ".deleted", Boolean.FALSE));
crit.add(Restrictions.eq(TAB2 + ".id", someId));
```

This "generates" a sql query like follow:

```
SELECT * FROM myClass this_
LEFT OUTER JOIN TAB1 tab1_ ON this_.id=tab1_.myClass_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN TAB2 tab2_ ON tab1_.tab2_id=tab2_.id
WHERE tab1_.deleted=0
AND tab2_.id = 1234
```

I need to put filters in the JOIN condition rather than in the WHERE clause.

To be clear, I need to have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM myClass this_
LEFT OUTER JOIN TAB1 tab1_ ON this_.id=tab1_.myClass_id AND tab1_.deleted=0
LEFT OUTER JOIN TAB2 tab2_ ON tab1_.tab2_id=tab2_.id AND AND tab2_.id = 1234
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using:

```
crit.createAlias(${table}, ${alias}, ${joinType});
```

You should be able to use:

```
crit.createAlias(${table}, ${alias}, ${joinType}, ${Criterion});
```

Although I could not find an example in our codebase, I would expect this to work.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think to looking for an overloading.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a decent example right from Hibernates confluence page:

```
public class PersonDao extends HibernateDaoSupport {
   public List<Person> findByName() { 
      Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Person.class, "p");
      criteria.createCriteria("p.names", "names", JoinType.INNER_JOIN, Restrictions.eq("name", "John")); 
      return criteria.list(); 
   }
}
```

**Produces**

```
select this_.id as y0_ from person this_ 
inner join debtor_info this_1_ on this_.id=this_1_.id 
left outer join person_person_name personname3_ on this_.id=personname3_.person_id and ( name1_.name=? ) 
left outer join person_name name1_ on personname3_.person_name_id=name1_.id and ( name1_.name=? )
```

With that example I believe your code should look something like

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(MyClass.class, "mine");
crit.createAlias("mine.names", "name", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN, Restrictions.eq("name", Boolean.FALSE));
crit.createAlias("q.id", "id", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN, Restrictions.eq("id", someId));
```